# Why are my drop down button menus and background image not working

Tags: html, css

I am trying to have a drop down menu while having a reptile image as the background, but I can't seem to have the drop down menu working with the image in it? When I take the image out, it works. I'm not sure if it's just because of the  that are being mixed up, or maybe it's a typing error, but I've looked and can't find any?

Another question is why my background color gradient (the gradient not reptile.png background one) is only showing only half the page. If you make the window smaller, it shows white and doesn't look good. I've tried using width/height : 100% 100%, cover, and tried stretching the image as height but it's not working. I would like to have the image stretch to the height and width of the page. I think it may be due to something about the body height, but I am not sure how to change that.

Here is the code

```css
  header {
    text-align: right;
    text-shadow: none;
  background-color: #a7a7a7;
  }

  body {
    background-image: linear-gradient(#545454, #000000);
  background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
     font-family: Gill Sans, "sans-serif";
   color: #f2fdec;
   font-size: 3em;
   text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #000000;
     padding: 0.2em;
      }

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  height: auto;
   opacity: 0.5;
}

h3 {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-family:
}

nav {
  font-weight: bold;
  float: right;
  color: #c1c1c1;
  font-size: 18px;
  padding: 8px 8px 8px 8px;
}

nav a:link {
  color: #f3ffe7;
  text-decoration: none;
}

nav a:visited {
  color: #f3ffe7;
  text-decoration: none;
}

nav a:hover {
  color: #f3ffe7;
  text-decoration: none;
}

nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

nav ul ul {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #474747;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
  display: none;
}

nav ul ul li {
  border: 1px solid #00005D;
  display: block;
  width: 4em;
  padding-left: 1em;
  margin-left: 0;
}

nav li:hover ul {
  display: block;
}

footer {
  font-size: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #474747;
  padding: 8px;
  text-shadow: none;
  color: #d2d2d2;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
}

#wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

header,
nav,
footer {
  display: block;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}

.herp {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.dropbtn {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #4f4f4f;
  min-width: 160px;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #696969;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #3f5840;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Reptile Website</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="home.css">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
            </head>
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <header><nav><ul>
            <div class="dropdown">
                <button class="dropbtn">Home</button>
            </div>
            <div class="dropdown">
                <button class="dropbtn">Lizards</button>
                <div class="dropdown-content">
                    <a href="geckos.html">Geckos</a>
                    <a href="chameleons.html">Chameleons</a>
                    <a href="skinks.html">Skinks</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="dropdown">
                <button class="dropbtn">Big Lizards</button>
                <div class="dropdown-content">
                    <a href="iguanas.html">Iguanas</a>
                    <a href="tegus.html">Tegus</a>
                    <a href="monitors.html">Monitors</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="dropdown">
                <button class="dropbtn">Turtles</button>
                <div class="dropdown-content">
                    <a href="turtles.html">Turtles</a>
                    <a href="tortoises.html">Tortoises</a>
                    <a href="terrapins.html">Terrapins</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="dropdown">
                <button class="dropbtn">Snakes</button>
                <div class="dropdown-content">
                    <a href="colubrid.html">Colubrids</a>
                    <a href="python.html">Pythons</a>
                    <a href="constrictor.html">Constrictors</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="dropdown">
                <button class="dropbtn">Ambibians</button>
                <div class="dropdown-content">
                    <a href="newts.html">Newts</a>
                    <a href="salamanders.html">Salamanders</a>
                    <a href="frogsntoads.html">Frogs and Toads</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="dropdown">
                <button class="dropbtn">Expertise</button>
                <div class="dropdown-content">
                    <a href="turtles.html">Beginner</a>
                    <a href="tortoises.html">Intermediate</a>
                    <a href="terrapins.html">Complex</a>
                </div>
        </ul></nav></header>
        
        <div class="container">
            <img src="reptile.png" alt="Reptile Background">
                <div class="herp">Explore Herping<br>
                    <h3>Your home for Herpetology Information</h3> . 
  </div>
                 </div>
         <footer>
             <p>Sasha Batz | s1467218@student.mcckc.edu</p>
         </footer>
     </div>
  </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Where is the image you are referring to?

Comment: Towards the end of the HTML file, in the <div class="container"> , I have an image inserted there.

Answer (score 0):

**First Question:**

That image make its parent element `.container` cover the dropdown menu, so you cannot hover the dropdown menu.

You can use `z-index` to put it on the top:

```
.container {
    z-index: 10;
}
.container img {
    z-index: 11;
}
nav {
    z-index: 1001;
}
```

And don't make the text `Your home for Herpetology Information` at the top of menu.

**Second Question:**

In specific, all percentage-based sizes must inherit from parent block elements, and if any of those ancestors fail to specify a size, they are assumed to be sized at 0 x 0 pixels.

So you need to add this to your css code:

```
html {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}
header {
  text-align : right;
  text-shadow : none;
  background-color : #a7a7a7;
}
body {
  background-image : linear-gradient(#545454, #000000);
  background-size : 100% 100%;
  background-repeat : no-repeat;
  font-family : Gill Sans, "sans-serif";
  color : #f2fdec;
  font-size : 3em;
  text-shadow : 2px 2px 2px #000000;
  padding: 0.2em;
  height: 100%;
}
.container {
    z-index: 10;
}
.container img {
    z-index: 11;
}
.container .herp {
    z-index: 11;
}
.container .herp h3{
    z-index: 12;
}
nav {
    z-index: 1001;
}
img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height : 100%;
  height: auto;
  opacity : 0.5;
}
h3 {
  font-size : 18px;
  font-family :
}
nav {
  font-weight : bold;
  float : right;
  color : #c1c1c1;
  font-size : 18px;
  padding : 8px 8px 8px 8px;
}
nav a:link {
  color : #f3ffe7;
  text-decoration : none;
}
nav a:visited {
  color : #f3ffe7;
  text-decoration : none;
}
nav a:hover {
  color : #f3ffe7;
  text-decoration : none;
}
nav ul {
  list-style-type : none;
}
nav a {
  text-decoration : none;
}
nav ul ul {
  position : absolute;
  background-color : #474747;
  padding : 0;
  text-align : center;
  display : none;
}
nav ul ul li {
  border : 1px solid #00005D;
  display : block ;
  width : 4em;
  padding-left : 1em;
  margin-left : 0;
}
nav li:hover ul {
  display : block;
}
footer {
  font-size : 10px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #474747;
  padding : 8px;
  text-shadow : none;
  color : #d2d2d2;
  position : absolute;
  left : 0;
  width : 100%;
  bottom : 0;
}
#wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height : 100%;
}
header, nav, footer {
  display : block;
}
.container {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}
.herp {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.dropbtn {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  z-index: 1005;
}
.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #4f4f4f;
  min-width: 160px;
}
.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}
.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #696969;
}
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #3f5840;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Reptile Website</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="a.css">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <header><nav><ul>
            <div class="dropdown">
                <button class="dropbtn">Home</button> |
            </div>
            <div class="dropdown">
                <button class="dropbtn">Lizards</button> |
                <div class="dropdown-content">
                    <a href="geckos.html">Geckos</a>
                    <a href="chameleons.html">Chameleons</a>
                    <a href="skinks.html">Skinks</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="dropdown">
                <button class="dropbtn">Big Lizards</button> |
                <div class="dropdown-content">
                    <a href="iguanas.html">Iguanas</a>
                    <a href="tegus.html">Tegus</a>
                    <a href="monitors.html">Monitors</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="dropdown">
                <button class="dropbtn">Turtles</button> |
                <div class="dropdown-content">
                    <a href="turtles.html">Turtles</a>
                    <a href="tortoises.html">Tortoises</a>
                    <a href="terrapins.html">Terrapins</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="dropdown">
                <button class="dropbtn">Snakes</button> |
                <div class="dropdown-content">
                    <a href="colubrid.html">Colubrids</a>
                    <a href="python.html">Pythons</a>
                    <a href="constrictor.html">Constrictors</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="dropdown">
                <button class="dropbtn">Ambibians</button> |
                <div class="dropdown-content">
                    <a href="newts.html">Newts</a>
                    <a href="salamanders.html">Salamanders</a>
                    <a href="frogsntoads.html">Frogs and Toads</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="dropdown">
                <button class="dropbtn">Expertise</button> |
                <div class="dropdown-content">
                    <a href="turtles.html">Beginner</a>
                    <a href="tortoises.html">Intermediate</a>
                    <a href="terrapins.html">Complex</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="dropdown">
                <button class="dropbtn">Care</button>
                <div class="dropdown-content">
                    <a href="newts.html">Leopard Gecko</a>
                    <a href="salamanders.html">Bearded Dragon</a>
                    <a href="frogsntoads.html">Kenyan Sand Boa</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </ul></nav></header>

        <div class="container">
            <img src="reptile.png" alt="Reptile Background"/>
                <!-- <div class="herp">Explore Herping<br>
                    <h3>Your home for Herpetology Information</h3></div> -->
                </div>
        <footer>
            <p>footer</p>
        </footer>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ok, I have put that in place of the previous .container, but now when I hover over the menus, the drop downs are hiding behind the reptile cover image. And thank you, the gradient background now works.

Comment: If the number of your nav's ```z-index``` is bigger than the image's ```z-index```, it will make the nav cover the image.

Comment: Any way to change that?

Comment: Try to add ```z-index``` to your ```.dropdown```